# Using smtpjs to send the checkbox value of the form in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, smtp, smtpjs

I to use SmtpJS to capture the value of my form and send it to my email.

---

So far I can get the input value without any problems

but how do I get the value of the checked checkbox?

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="contact_us_title">Name</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="contact_us_title">Question</label>
   <div >
     <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Ａ</label>
     <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Ｂ</label>
     <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Ｃ</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
    <script>
    function sendMail() {
      let fields = {
        name: document.querySelector("#name").value,
      };
      let body = 'Name：' + fields.name;
      Email.send({
        Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
        Username : "username",
        Password : "password",
        To : 'them@website.com',
        From : "you@isp.com",
        Subject: "title",
        Body: body,
      }).then(
              message => alert(message)
      );
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added submit button to call sendMail function and added class and update value of checkbox to get values!

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="contact_us_title">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="contact_us_title">Question</label>
  <div>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"
      ><input type="checkbox" class="ques" value="A" />Ａ</label
    >
    <label class="checkbox-inline"
      ><input type="checkbox" class="ques" value="B" />Ｂ</label
    >
    <label class="checkbox-inline"
      ><input type="checkbox" class="ques" value="C" />Ｃ</label
    >
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="sendMail()" />

<script>
  function sendMail() {
    const questionValues = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ques:checked')].map(
      (e) => e.value
    );
    let fields = {
      name: document.querySelector('#name').value,
      question: questionValues,
    };
    console.log(fields);
    let body = 'Name：' + fields.name;
     Email.send({
       Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
       Username : "username",
       Password : "password",
       To : 'them@website.com',
       From : "you@isp.com",
       Subject: "title",
       Body: body,
     }).then(
             message => alert(message)
     );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I got the value, but after I add it here, no matter whether I check multiple checkboxes or not, the value displayed will only have the first one. Could you tell me which side I did wrong?

Comment: let body = 'Name：' + fields.name + '<br>' + 'Question：' + fields.question;

Comment: @KrystalTabo you want multiple value of checkbox right ?

Comment: @KrystalTabo Now it will give multiple checkbox values! Check the updated one.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much ❤️❤️❤️